# Show $a+bi \equiv 0,1 \pmod{1+i}$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

This is a problem (self-studier) from Ireland & Rosen (3.23):

Show $a+bi \equiv 0,1 \pmod{1+i}$ with $a,b \in\mathbb{Z}$.

There is an extensive hint/solution offered, some parts of which I would appreciate help understanding.

To begin, it says $i\equiv -1(1+i)\pmod{1+i}$ No problem here.

Then it says write $a+ib \equiv a-b \pmod{1+i}$. Here I think the $a$ remains intact since $(1+i) \nmid a$

Write $a-b$ as $2c+d$ where $d=0,1$. This makes sense as $a,b$ are integers and their difference will be either even or odd.

So here is where I am stuck.

Then $a+ib \equiv a-b \equiv 2c+d \equiv d\pmod{1+i}$

How is $2c \equiv 0 \pmod{1+i}$ when $a$  was not a few lines above, since they are both in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Thanks

Comment: I think that what would really help you here more than anything else is to plot a small section of the complex plane and put dots for all the multiples of $1 + i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $2=(1+i)(1-i)$, so $(1+i)\mid 2$.

*Remark*: It may be more useful to show that $1+i$ divides $a+bi$ if and only if $a$ and $b$ are both even or both odd.

Comment: Thanks for this. I was able to apply the concept to the next problem to show $a+b\omega \equiv -1,0,1 \pmod{1-\omega}$. With regards,

Comment: You are welcome. Good!

Answer (score 2):

I think the two equivalences $$a + bi \equiv a - b \pmod{1 + i}$$ and $$s \equiv  0, 1 \pmod 2 \qquad s \in \mathbb{Z}$$ along with Andre's comment  that $1 + i \mid 2$ gives a simple solution.

Answer (score 2):

$a + ib \equiv a + (-1)b$ because we have just shown that $i \equiv -1$.

But $i \equiv -1$ implies $1 = -1 \cdot -1 \equiv i \cdot i = -1$. Add 1 to both sides to get $2 \equiv 0$. All equivalences modulo $(1+i)$.